# Diagnosing slow sshfs transfer speeds (as compared to http)

Tags: file-copy, sshfs

I've been trying to set up a way to transfer a reasonable amount of data between two servers (remote and local, both running ubuntu server), including some backups (zipped), pictures, home movies, general files, etc. I very much enjoy the convinience of using sshfs to mount a remote directory on my machine, which lets me interact with the changing files easily.

The issue is that transfer speeds with this are quite slow, and I can't seem to figure out why. With sshfs, copying a file (rsync) runs at about ~2mb/s, whereas downloading the same file over https (wgetto dl/nginx to host) runs at about ~26mb/s - substantially faster. Of course, I could go through and set it all up manually and download the files, but I'd like to not have to repeat that process so much, as well as be able to make changes on the remote machine.

In short, ideally, I'd like to be able to use sshfs (or some other utility which lets me mount) without such a drastic speed penalty.

I've tried using the following options with sshfs as I found them recommended in a related answer but none seem to impact the speed: `-o Compression=no -oauto_cache,reconnect,no_readahead`

Using rsync from the local machine directly gives better speeds (about 16mb/s)

Have I missed something here? This seems to be abnormal behavior to me and I'm not sure how to diagnose further.